# AngularJs Can't fill select list with object

Tags: angularjs

I have modal that included a select list .

here is our object in `console.log`:

```
 Object
config: Object
data: Array[1]
0: Object
__rowIndex: 0
dateTimeFormat: 0
deptCode: 325
```

and our Html :

```
 <select
 ng-options="item.DeptCode as item.dateTimeFormat for item in WFFormOperatorViewMap.data"
 ng-model="singData.ReceiverCode">

<option value="value" selected style="display:none">انتخاب</option>

 </select>
```

and controller:

```
  $scope.WFFormOperatorViewMap = [];
var getReceivers = function ()
    {
        createSingData();
        BaseService.postData(urlBase + 'GetReceivers', $scope.singData).then(function (data)
        {
            debugger;

            $scope.WFFormOperatorViewMap = data;
            console.log($scope.WFFormOperatorViewMap);
        })
    }
```

Any Idea?

Comment: DeptCode != deptCode. Case matters. Your code would also be much clearer if you named the data variable `response`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion, solved my problem
please put this in answer section

Comment: I'll rather vote to close, because it's a simple typo problem.

Comment: ok @JBNizet, that's better